VSCode doesn't show golangci-linter errors
I can't see the linter errors as problems in VS Code.
Here is my setup:
I am using VS Code without a .golangci.yml config file. Golangci-linter is installed and works. I can run golangci-lint run --fast on my terminal and get the expected output.
Here is my VS Code settings.json:

{
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": false,
  "editor.formatOnType": false,
  // remove any code actions that are configured to run on save
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": [],
  // put a ruler on the editing screen at 120 characters
  "editor.rulers": [160],
  "editor.wordWrap": "wordWrapColumn",
  "editor.wordWrapColumn": 160,

  "[go]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "golang.go",
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.organizeImports": "always",
      "source.fixAll": "always",
    }
  },
 // make sure the go language server is enabled
 "go.useLanguageServer": true,
 // configure gopls, the go language server
 "gopls": {
   "ui.semanticTokens": true,
   "ui.completion.usePlaceholders": true
 },
   // configure the go formatting tool to be goimports
   "go.formatTool": "goimports",
   "go.formatFlags": [
     "-local",
   ],

   // change the linting tool to be golangci
   "go.lintTool": "golangci-lint",
   "go.lintOnSave": "workspace",
   "go.lintFlags": [
     "--fast"
   ],

   // dont run code coverage on save
  "go.coverOnSave": false,
}


In the problems tab I only see compiler errors but no linter errors.

How can I fix or debug the issue further?

I've been trying to work through this issue too. The only thing that's worked for me is to explicitly enable rules within the config file. e.g. I listed out the default rules that are turned on within the "linters enable" section, and now they're showing up in the Problems tab within VSCode, as well as highlighted in the code.
